# Script possibly in C# for controlling a program

Tags: c#

This is pretty much new to me and the web didn't help much.
Goal: To make a script which would control screen video capture then send it to server.

How to make the script ?
is it possible to make it in C#?
any guides that you guys can recommend ?

Edit: More Details:

Need a Script-> When launched it would run a screen capture program(camtasia probably)->Then it would automatically send the saved file to a server.
My problem is I do not know where to start or what to look at ... hope this helps

Comment: Added more, not sure how more specific i can be ... maybe ask me a question ?

Comment: This is pretty vague. You should consider breaking this down into individual, smaller, more specific questions. Questions like "How do I write X application" generally don't get a lot of responses.

Comment: Well, the thing is i'm really lost into where i should start to make a script? I would just look up batch but then i wouldn't know if it can handle playing with programs. Just need a push on the back for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question. You are asking how to interact with a program that (I assume) you didn't develop. You could use C# to launch the application, but unless the application has built in some sort of API for you to programatically control it with, then your out of luck.

Your first step would be to find a program that has an external API or excepts external arguments via a command line program that you can use to control it. I am not sure I've ever heard of screen capture software with such an API. Your need sounds very unique and I'm just guessing that you aren't likely going to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a batch file or a powershell script; the main issue you're going to have is finding a video capture program which allows itself to be controlled from the command line.

Assuming you find one, something like this would work:

```
C:\Program Files\Capture\Capture.exe /length: 5 /output: C:\Videos\Video1.avi
```

Then you'd need to FTP the output file over to a server.

As for doing this in C#, that would work just as well as batch file or powershell; but either way, the program you are using to do the video capture would need to provide a mechanism for controlling it through an API or command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're wanting to automate interaction with Camtasia, you should first look to see if that application has an API.  If it doesn't, one option you have available is to write a script to automate UI interactions with the application.  Wikipedia has a [pretty good list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) of the types of toolkits that can help you with that.  I've heard good things about [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt), for example.

Comment: While this is possible, automating UI interactions programatically is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Thank you, really useful! All three answers gonna get me started thanks guys. 
@chevex yeah but last resort :P and my heart still young and beating hard ! :P